# ProTeXt with MiKTeX downloading issue

Tags: miktex2.9, protext

I used ProTeXt to download MiKTeX, and after ProTeXt finished I began downloading MiKTeX. It's been downloading for many hours now, and I was wondering if this is normal. I keep getting the error "A timeout was reached while receiving data from the server"

Comment: The latest version of MikTeX is dated 1/4/2019 and has several important bug fixes.

Comment: ProTeXt is a very large file of about 2GB. To download it, it is better to use a web browser that manages breaks like Chrome with `chrome://flags/#enable-download-resumption`. [Google Chrome: Enabling download resumption](https://www.djangospin.com/google-chrome-enabling-download-resumption/)

Comment: protext is updated about once a year latest was 13-Dec-2017 so simplest way to get the latest is -- 1) download and install single user full MiKTeX (however if you dont need full I would recommend a smaller basic portable, but sort out the paths and test inbuilt editor / updates first) -- 2) Then download and install latest TeXstudio (if you really want it as a secondary editor)

Comment: @KJO no. Last update 27/04/2018 see : [Index de /historic/systems/protext/](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/protext/)

Comment: @AndréC follow your link and see upload date

Comment: @KJO You're right. The information changes with each page!

Comment: Hm, is your issue solved? If not download ProTeXt from https://ctan.org/pkg/protext it contains the current version from 2019 ...